# mongoose model disable remove

Tags: javascript, mongoose

i want disable remove docs in some doc model.
Inside doc pre hook I can do somthing like that:

```
someSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
  let err = new Error('Delete docs is not allowed!');
  next(err);
});
```

But remove still can be executed by someModel.remove()
How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer was simple: just override remove fun like this:

```
let model = mongoose.model('doc', someDocSchema);
model.remove = function () {
  throw new Error('Delete docs is not allowed!');
};
```

Comment: There are also `findOneAndRemove`, `findByIdAndRemove` and `Model.find().remove()`